# Python: Instance of BaseHTTPRequestHandler resets after GET Request

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I have a `python BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class that is called by an `HTTPServer` class. Basically the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` just runs a basic algorithm and then responds to a `Get` request. The issue is that every time I do a `Get` request, I get the correct response but all the gathered data in `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` is reset as if each time a request is sent to the `HTTPServer` it creates a new instance of `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. I can't find anything online that really explains what's going on behind the scenes. I've attached a simplified version of my code. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Before anyone suggests creating a class or global variable, I am using a thread to create multiple instances of this class at once and doing so makes all the instances on each thread share and replace each other's data.

CODE (indentation off when copy and pasted)

**BaseHTTPRequestHandler**

This simplified version just keeps track of the number of alerts that have happened. The problem is that the count always resets to 0 when I call a `Get` request as if the instance of the class is reset.

```
class SimulationServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def __init__(self, address, port, randomNumberMax, *args):
    self.IP_ADDRESS = address
    self.PORT = port
    self.RANDOM_NUMBER_MAX = randomNumberMax
    self.COUNT = 0
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args)

def do_GET(self):
    if self.headers['Authorization'] == 'Basic ' + str(key):
        print("send response")
        self.do_HEAD()
        randomNumberMax = self.RANDOM_NUMBER_MAX
        response = ""

        if randint(0, randomNumberMax) == 0:
            self.generateAlert()

        base_path = urlparse(self.path).path
        print('base_path: ' + base_path)
        if base_path == '/count':
            response = self.getCount()

        self.wfile.write(bytes(response, 'utf-8'))

def getCount(self):
    count = self.COUNT
    jsonString = '{"_sig": "","count": ' + str(count) + '}'
    return jsonString

def generateAlert(self):
    newAlert = {}
    newAlert['siteId'] = "siteId"+ str(self.COUNT)
    newAlert['mesg'] = "Simulated Alert"
    newAlert['when'] = int(time.time())

    self.COUNT += 1
```

**HTTPServer**

```
class CustomHTTPServer(HTTPServer):
key = ''

def __init__(self, address, handlerClass=SimulationServer):
    super().__init__(address, handlerClass)

def set_auth(self, username, password):
    self.key = base64.b64encode(
        bytes('%s:%s' % (username, password), 'utf-8')).decode('ascii')

def get_auth_key(self):
    return self.key
```

**Main**

This class creates the `HTTPServer` and attaches the `handler`

```
class RunSimulator(object):
def run(self, alertFrequency=50, port=9000):
    ipAddress="127.0.0.1"
    def handler(*args):
        SimulationServer(ipAddress, port, alertFrequency, *args)

    simulationServer = CustomHTTPServer((ipAddress, port), handler)
    simulationServer.set_auth('username', 'password')

    try:
        simulationServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    simulationServer.server_close()
    print(time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (ipAddress, port))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv
    simu = RunSimulator()
    simu.run()
```

Comment: Specifically what data is lost. The request handler is not reusable per se so data is expected to get lost.

Comment: The count (iterator) is reset not when i dona GET request. I know that the count will be reset when i close the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the short answer is that it does create a new instance every time a request is sent.

`BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer` is a subclass of `SocketServer.TCPServer` which itself is a subclass of `SocketServer.BaseServer`. Every time a request comes in it will process the request `process_request` and then call `finish_request`. `finish_request` will instantiate a fresh instance of whatever your request handler is.

Comment: Very helpful thank you, I know how to get around losing the count, I just hoped there was some work around.